# USB burnt 17.10 iso from Startup Disk Creator corrupted

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I have tried many methods in the internet and every time I get a corrupted "burnt" USB image from the official "ubuntu-17.10-desktop-amd64.iso" file.
The image either gets burned with 2048 bytes block size, instead of 512, or gets burned correctly (with 7_zip) but won't boot.

Even the official "Startup Disk Creator" won't do the job right.

I believe there is something wrong with the official file.
PS: the SHA256SUM has been checked

Comment: I use `mkusb` to create a Live USB - it's available via PPA at [https://launchpad.net/~mkusb/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~mkusb/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Comment: Is the image when burned by startup disk creator showing a message about `gfxboot` or something like that when you try to boot it?

Comment: If you are running the Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (or a newer version), it is using the very robust cloning method, and I think it is creating a good USB boot drive (as well as mkusb). **Have you tried to boot from the USB boot drive?** There are tools, for example gparted, that do not understand a cloned USB boot drive, and complain about it. The output that you get indicates such a problem. - But if you try with the Startup Disk Creator in older Ubuntu versions, for example in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, there are several bugs, that cause problems.

Comment: mkusb if you are making the USB from a Linux machine or YUMI if you are using Windows machine. Rufus if you don't need persistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [sudodus](https://askubuntu.com/users/55537/sudodus) to point out that gparted does not play well with cloned USB boot drive.

Actually my problem was that the first method I used to burn the image on the USB stick didn't work because it would not boot. Then I used gparted to check if the partition was really bootable. With no luck after other methods, I found out about the Startup Disk Creator and while checking the image with gparted before trying to boot I thought the image was corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

you should check [Etcher](https://github.com/resin-io/etcher), which is a great tool for flashing ISO images to usb drives.

I've flashed the 17.10 ubuntu ISO to a 2GB drive just yesterday. Worked as a charm.

Comment: Etcher is nice. it shows the `iso` file is bootable or not before writing to usb drive.